# MATLAB - the function returns unwanted output

Tags: matlab, function

and I am pretty new at it. I wrote the simple function below, which gets a pair and returns the polar form

```
function [r,a] = rect2polar(x,y)
    r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2);
    a = atan(y/x);
    [r,a]
end
```

and when I try for example rect2polar(3,5) it gives me the next output:

```
ans =
5.8310    1.0304

ans =
5.8310
```

It returns the desired output, plus the output 5.8310, in other words it returns the variable r in the function for the second time. How can I fix this? Writing

```
rect2polar(3,5);
```

helped (the difference is that I wrote ; at the end), but it doesn't feel right. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It has to do with the last line in your function. This last line will cause the variables `r` and `a` to be displayed when the function is run.

The second output you are seeing is the output of your function; however it will only write the first variable to `ans`. 

You should delete the last line (`[r,a]`) in your function, and call it with [r,a] = rect2polar(x,y).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first displayed part,

```
ans =
   5.8310 1.0304
```

is produced by this line in your function

```
[r,a]
```

Since it is missing a `;`, Matlab displays the result.

The second part,

```
ans =
   5.8310
```

is produced because when you call the function as `rect2polar(3,5)` you are indicating that you want only one output, namely the first, which is displayed after the function returns.

So, the solution would be:

- Remove the line `[r, a]` in your function, which is doing nothing but display what the function will output;
- Call your function as `[out1, out2] = rect2polar(3,5)`.

Or, if you want the function to return a vector:

```
function out = rect2polar(x,y)
    r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2);
    a = atan(y/x);
    out = [r,a];
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! It's still not clear to me, because  I want the function to get a pair and will return vector of the polar coordinates, so I do want the first output (which gives 5.8310 1.0304) but not the second (which is 5.3810). if I remove the line [r,a] then it does not return the the first answer (5.8310 1.0304) and only returns the second output (5.8310) which I don't want. I entered the line [out1, out2] = rect2polar(3,5) , it just gives assigns to out1 and out2 (and prints it) the values 5.83310 1.0304 respectivly, which is not what i want. I just want a vector output of 2values

Comment: Or I am misunderstanding something. The fact that I wrote
    function [r,a] = rect2polar(x,y)
doesn;t it mean the output has to be a vector of two enteries? I was taught the way it works is
    function output = function_name(input)

Comment: @mathstackuser123 With the signature `[r,a] = rect2polar(x,y)` you have two outputs, not one vector output. To get that you need to define the function as `out = rect2polar(x,u)` and build `out` as a vector within the function body. See edited answer

Comment: Thanks for the help!